# How to import data in mysql from oracle cvs?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have an sql file which looks a bit strange : `66611118192;13847372372281881112@deleted;;223115;52118122@Deleted;` Any idea how can I import it in mysql ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use `;` as a delimiter.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test (column1, column2, ...)
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: how do I set the order of import ? I mean  which data inserts in which fields.

Comment: @user2072671 Read the documentation. It's pretty explicit. I'll update my answer.

Comment: never liked mysql doc ... it has too many options and not even an example

Comment: @user2072671 Then I would recommend doing a little research.

Comment: the example is great but I think the syntax is wrong . It says ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'' at line 3

Comment: It's pseduo-code. Post a new question after you research your error.